# While sending mail a href link is not clickable in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sendmail, html-email, phpmailer

In the below code when I send the mail href link display whole url and not clickable it is shown as below:-
Click on the following link :
[click here for confirmation](http://abc.com/xyz/test.php?user_id=dTM=&key=bUl2MDJdfMN2w1cUNZ)
This display correctly on local but on server it is incorrect.
Please reply if not getting my point.

```
$key = stripslashes($user->user_activation_key);

$activation_key = base64_encode($key);
$user_id_enc = base64_encode($user_id);


$siteUrl = get_site_url();
$full_Url=$siteUrl.'/test.php?user_id='.$user_id_enc.'&key='.$activation_key;
$message  = __('Click on the following link:') . "</br>\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('<a href="%s">click here for confirmation</a>'), $full_Url) . "\r\n";
  wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your confirmatiom'), $blogname), $message);
```

Comment: <a href="http://abc.com/xyz/test.php?user_id=MTM=&key=bUlNZ"> click here for confirmation</a>

Comment: plz reply of above question.if anyone wants to get other details plz comment.

Answer (score 0):

try using the absolute path for the link with http://abc.com.
Also, make sure the website is not network specific eg. can be accessed just inside your work network.